# woocommerce popup window after add to cart

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I need display cart content popup with addet items.
what hooks i used:

```
woocommerce_add_to_cart
woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart
```

How i use it(for example):

```
function popup_window_woo() {
//here can be some code like $('.popup-container').popup();
echo "<script>console.log('sometext');</script>";
}
add_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', 'popup_window_woo');
```

But if i do that - ajax loader spin again and again. that's all.

what i doing wrong?

Comment: The add to cart button is spinning because your script code is being added to the server response for the `woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart` response.  The javascript on the front end is expecting a json response from the server but instead receives the script (with the json response behind it). I'll try to remind myself to look at this closer later, but there's a good start for you.

Comment: Just need some hook, who said(figuratively) - "alright is sparky, product has been added successfully, now u can run your modal window with cart content!"
(Without reload page ofc)